# Control volume OSD on Ubuntu 18.10 with python

Tags: python

I'm making a volume control knob with Arduino(because they are hecking expensive to buy). To do so I need software that actually controls the volume. Now I know how to control the volume by calling amixer, but I want to do it the way keyboards do it, so that it shows the ubuntu volume OSD to indicate how much volume you set it to. Is it possible to do that with Ubuntu and Python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [xdotool to simulate media key presses](https://askubuntu.com/q/235126/6932):

```
xdotool key XF86AudioLowerVolume
xdotool key XF86AudioRaiseVolume
```

Otherwise you might want to try pactl tool if your system uses PulseAudio.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick! I do have to note that you have to install xdotool first(sudo apt-get install xdotool). Just in case someone doesn't know.

Comment: I know the original question was about Ubuntu, but can you address this topic on windows? How media keys are different from ordinary keys? Can Python itself simulate the mediakey press?

Comment: @handras There's nothing special about media keys, simulating keyboard events requires calling OS specific system calls. In Windows, you can do this by calling Win32 API like SendInput or keybd_event using [pywin32](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32), or by writing your low level binding with [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) or cffi. Or alternatively if you want to do this in platform independent way, with wrappers like [keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/).